# C# - connecting Slider to TextBox and read in TextBox value

Tags: c#, slider

I have in my MainPage() the following line of code:

```
string str = tbx1.Text;
```

Then I have a slider that changes this TextBox:

```
    private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Slider slider1 = sender as Slider;
        tbx1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();

    }
```

When I run the app the default value of `tbx1` is read in, and it can be changed with the slider. But how do I read in the new value of `tbx1` into `str`? It seems that only the default value is kept in `str`.

Comment: Where is the code for string str = tbx1.Text?  if you move the variable str to a member level then you can update it in slider changed event

Comment: depending on what you are doing with the string variable do you even need it? you could just access the text box text directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the string in a property and access it dynamically:

```
string Str
{
    get { return tbx1.Text; }
    set { tbx1.Text = value; }
}
```

If you only need to read the string then you can drop the setter:

```
string Str
{
    get { return tbx1.Text; }
}
```

Use the property `Str` instead of the variable `str`. This will always yield the actual value (example):

```
string result = Str;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you could directly get the value from the slider.

```
string Str
{
    get { return slider1.Value.ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: Where do I have to put string result = Str;? Inside the slider code it does not work.

Comment: `string result = Str;` just simulates reading `str`. It is just an example. Place it (or what code ever you need) where you accessed `str` before. You really don't need to have this `string result =`. I could have written `Console.WriteLine(Str);` as well. The property `Str` is a dynamic replacement for the variable `str`.

Comment: Wherever I place it, the value of the original string is not replaced by the new value. What to do now?

Comment: The idea is that you use the property `Str` **instead** of the string variable `str`. Remove the variable `str`!

Comment: I tried that in the MainPage() as well as in the slider method. Both do not work. The result is not being updated.

Comment: The `Str` property always retrieves the actual value from the textbox, so you will always see the actual text of the textbox when reading `Str`! (You still need to do `tbx1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();` in `Slider_ValueChanged_1` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If string is accessable you can do the following

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider slider1 = sender as Slider;
    tbx1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();
    str = slider1.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change str when `tbx1.Text` you can do that :

youcan declare your value in your class

```
private string _str
```

then you have to make your code : (you have to add Leave function to your textbox)

```
private void tbx1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _str = tbx1.Text;
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider slider1 = sender as Slider;
    _str = tbx1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Where do I have to put string str = tbx1.Text; then?

Comment: @user1189952 the Slider_ValueChanged_1 at the main page or in another window ?

Comment: The string still does not take the new value. I do not understand why and how to resolve this.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `_str = tbx1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();` and you will see if the variable is updated or not.